# Why does flowtype complain about my array definition in my reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype, reducers

This is my definition for a pupil object:

```
type PupilType = {
  classId: string,
  created: number,
  description: string,
  firstname: string,
  gender: string,
  id: string,
  lastname: string,
  updated: number,
};
```

And this is my pupil redux reducer, the pupils are kept in an array:

```
export default function reducer(state: Array<Object> = [], action: Object) 
{
    ...
}
```

This works, but if rather than just saying the array contains Objects I try and use the type like this:

```
export default function reducer(state: Array<PupilType> = [], action: Object) 
{
    ...
}
```

flowtype says there is an error:

**"array literal This type is incompatible with the expected param type of array type"**

Why is this? I can use

```
Array<PupilType>
```

elsewhere in my app just fine. It's only in the reducer that it seems to cause a problem.

Comment: maybe cuz you're defining a default value that's empty but your type shows a populated array.  Try `(state: Array<PupilType> = [pupil] ...`

Comment: I get [no errors...](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACgrmAlgGwCrmgXigbwFBRQDGyAhgM7kCSAJgFxTnABOiAdgOYA0BxzEpYBHpQ2cALYAjCMx6EaEckVZhgiAPZsGTVpzlQAZomZM2pcRG0t23XhwhsFzK7tuFEInTf1lT5y4zWerwINILCDGJSMjwAvgDceEkQAB5g6szAUAoGpHDIWQZwbERqmlD8NHBEMgAUTOEMAILMzKQgADzwSGgYAHxQ2ADaALpcUKSlGlpQAPKSAFYQpQCUuLx4sbyEeEA). Maybe you can share the link with an error the same way.

Comment: Eh, it's hard to diagnose this without a working example. Can you trim it down to the relevant flowtypes and post on https://flow.org/try ?

Comment: A (likely wrong) shot in the dark: maybe check out $ReadOnlyArray<PupilType>, a read-only version of Arrays. Sometimes that fixes issues I have with Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
export default function reducer(state: Array<PupilType>, action: Object) 
{
    ...
}
```